# Regex: Omit file extension

Tags: java, regex

I am writing a regex to pull the filename from a Linux file-path e.g:

```
/snowninja/Documents/filename.txt`
```

The file name can have spaces in it.

Here is the regex: `^/(.+/)*(.+)/(.+)$` that I  use to select filepaths 
and then get the filenames by `$3`

This picks up even the file extension and I don't want that.
Any help is appreciated.
T

Comment: You should tell us the language you are using (Java, JS, Python...) for a better answer. Although a bit clumsy, this is my regex raw try: `^\/.+\/.+\/([^\.]+)`. This will not work if the filename contains one or more dots.

Comment: I am using the Replace in String step on Pentaho PDI (I think it uses java). Your regex works great for my need

Comment: @PatoGichini Would you mind adding the language in the tags of the question please?

Comment: I've added. I am not a 100% sure that the step I explained above uses java though. Feel free to change if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with the following regex : **[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bEsq0H/1/)**

```
(?<=\/)[^.\/]+(?=[.])
(?<=/)[^./]+(?=[.]) <-- unescaped
```

It proceeds to do a positive lookbehind to find a `/`, picks everything after it that is not a `.` or a `/` and stop when finding a `.` (positive lookahead) to make sure you're taking the file and not the directories

Comment: While this might work in most cases, it's not a correct solution as will not work with filenames containing a dot (my.file.txt) or filenames that do not have a file extension (mydatafile) or only the extension part without the filename part (e.g. .gitignore)

Comment: @DanieleTorino It's an iffy business anyway, seeing as there is such a thing as `.tar.gz` files. But, yes, normally it should take the _last_ dot. It should be something more along the lines of `(?<=/)([^/]+)(?=[.][^./]+$)`